# How to pass session variables when header redirects? loosing session variables during the process of redirection

Tags: php, session, redirect, logout

> session varibales

```
<?php session_start(); 
error_reporting(-1);
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
}
$total_amt=$_POST['total_amt'];
$total_seats=$_POST['total_seats'];
$seat=$_POST['seat'];
$boarding_point=$_POST['boarding_point'];
$submit=$_POST['chksbmt'];
$_SESSION['total_amt']=$total_amt;
$_SESSION['total_seats']=$total_seats;
$_SESSION['seat']=$seat;
$_SESSION['boarding_point']=$boarding_point;
$_SESSION['chksbmt']=$submit;
?>

<?php
$serial_no = 1;
$total_seats = $_SESSION['total_seats']; 
$seats=explode(',', rtrim($total_seats, ","));
foreach ($seats as $seat) { ?>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;"> <?php echo $serial_no++; ?></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $seat; ?> </td>
```

& so on ..

login div

```
<ul class="top">
         <li><a href="registration.php" class="about">Registration</a>
        </li>
       <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { ?>
        <li class="hover"><a href="#" onClick="revealModal('modalPage')">Login</a>
        </li>
         <?php } else {?>
        <li class="hover"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    <div style="color:#00CC66;">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user'];     ?></div>
         <?php } ?>
              </ul>
```

> logout.php

```
<?php session_start();
session_destroy(); 
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
exit;  
?>
```

When m logging out from my page, it has to be redirected & in this process i m loosing my session variables. Is that any process to keep the variables constant after the redirection .. After the page redirection m getting undefined index error.. Any help .. ?? Thank you in advance

Comment: why there is a downvote? do you guys even read the question?

Comment: thank you so much for this... @Letmesee i also wondered for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're destroying whole session on logout page. While you just need to unset the relevant session key.

Something like,

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['login_user']); //session_destroy(); 
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
exit;
```

Comment: hey thankss :)  but is their any method to refresh the page only without giving this 1 header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: yeah i ve given session in count also.. it's working in some case, after redirection my session variables getting lost

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `session_destroy();`
 you should use `unset($_SESSION['login_user']);`
It will change the value of the variable in the session to **null** and **you will not lose your variable**. `session_destroy()` destroys the session completely and then you have no way to access that variable.
You can check the difference between them using var_dump
 eg:- `session_destroy(); var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']);`
 **and** 
`unset($_SESSION['login_user']); var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']);`
**AND** in your code

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
}
```

**you should not keep it blank. I think you forgot to include the following code inside this block**

Comment: thank you .. worked :)  but is their any method to refresh the page only without giving this 1 header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: you can refresh the page using **$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];**

Comment: hey i just got through ur last of ans , u r sayin dat i shouldnt left blank this place if (!isset($_SESSION)){ ... what should i put der ??